# C++: various encodings getters like in Python

Tags: c++, python, encoding, icu

My question is about encodings under C++. When I've worked with Python, I've sometimes had to use such encodings for various needs:

```
sys.stdin.encoding
sys.stdout.encoding
sys.stderr.encoding
sys.getfilesystemencoding()
sys.getdefaultencoding()
locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
```

Now there is a question: is there a cross-platform way to to something like it in C++? I know that I could see Python's sources, but probably there are some solutions  which are famous to people who use C++ and there is no need to see Python's sources. I think that for locale I can use `#include <locale>` or `#include <clocale>`; under Linux I can also use `getenv("LANG")` from `<cstdlib>`. Is there anything else?

If it can help, I have working `ICU` library.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to know how to map any possible line of Python involving encodings (without even mentioning 2.x vs. 3.x) to POSIX, libstd++, or ICU code, that's way too broad a question to answer.

Comment: I want to get encodings for stdin, stdout, stderr, default filesystem encoding, locale encoding, if it is possible to get them in C/C++.

Comment: There are no encodings for stdin, stdout, stderr in C++; they're just plain `FILE*` objects, which don't carry any encoding; they effectively just deal with streams of bytes without caring what those bytes mean. So, the answer to your literal question is that it's impossible. But if you explain the higher-level problem you're trying to solve, there probably _is_ a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to the question, as it doesn't provide a platform-independent solution, but I'm going present some things I've found while trying to get at an answer.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc
#moreso locales than encodings

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html (from* functions)

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html

I could not find any documentation pertaining to the mode of cin (binary vs text vs which encoding).
If it is text mode, it will be difficult (or impossible) to find the exact source bytes prior to any alterations.
In order to properly process the bytes, there (likely?) needs to be some type of codec -matching (or detecting) between the input to the application, and the internals of the application. This is probably a lost cause unless you can find the codec of cin (and there is a well-defined decode/encode mapping), and encode the string back to bytes, and then decode the bytes into whatever the app requires.

That said, if you use some interesting side-hacks, like re-opening cin, opening /dev/stdin, etc. you might be able to work around this limitation on some platforms.

The general solution is likely to not use the automagically opened files at all, but to instead use more controlled files/streams/pipes, etc, where the app, and the other pieces within its flow, can communicate on some agreed-upon convention.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494240)